# Local Storage vs Cookies vs Endpoint -> Best Practise to keep app authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, frontend

I'm just wondering. Time in our tech world is going so fast and I'm just curious what type of authentication is the best solution today. When we talk about performance, security + different areas.

For example

When the User is login into the application what would be the best way to keep the information about authentication?

**CASE 1**

Lets keep some information in the Cookie and ask every time cookie if there some property exists to keep user logged in

**CASE 2**

Lets keep the same information but in the local Storage or session storage and ask it every time to keep user logged in

**CASE 3**

Lets ask every time / on every screen the backend if that user exists / is logged in to make sure that we should keep this user logged in - Here I know that we can have something like `Redux` to keep the state, but what if user will reload the page? Then we will have to send another endpoint

**Summary**

In these 3 cases which approach would be the best and why? What do you think?